# Set "content Security Policy" dynamically in play 2.5

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, guice, content-security-policy

Play recommanded way to set the "content Security Policy" is to set the

```
play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy
```

in the application.conf.

But my requirement is to set this dynamically in the code by reading some custom entries in a override configuration file.

Can some please suggest a way to set contentSecurityPolicy in Play programmatic by overriding the value play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy in application.conf.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"? You need different values for different url's in your app? Can you give a concise example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my requiremnet was to extend GuiceApplicationLoader.
[(Play documentation on this.)](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Advanced:-Extending-the-GuiceApplicationLoader)

// The following solution is to combine the "play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy" in the application config with another custom setting in the application config overide.

```
public class MyApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {

@Override
public GuiceApplicationBuilder builder(ApplicationLoader.Context context) {   

    String trustedserverList = "";
    if (context.initialConfiguration().getString("custom.csp.trusted.serverlist") != null ){
        trustedserverList = context.initialConfiguration().getString("custom.csp.trusted.serverlist"); 
    }

    for ( Iterator<Entry<String, ConfigValue>> iter = context.initialConfiguration().entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        Entry<String, ConfigValue> con = iter.next();

        if (StringUtils.equals(con.getKey(), "play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy")) {
            String csp = context.initialConfiguration().getString("play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy");
            csp = String.format(csp,trustedserverList);                     
            Configuration extra = new Configuration("play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy=\"" + csp + "\"");              
            return initialBuilder
                    .in(context.environment())
                    .loadConfig(extra.withFallback(context.initialConfiguration()))
                    .overrides(overrides(context));
        }
    }   
    return initialBuilder
        .in(context.environment())
        .loadConfig(context.initialConfiguration())
        .overrides(overrides(context));
}
```

}

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this -- you can add your own EssentialFilter that adds a `Content-Security-Policy` header, and disable the contentSecurityHeader line by setting it to null.  See https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-chatroom-example/blob/2.6.x/app/filters/ContentSecurityPolicyFilter.scala for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a page specific override:

application.conf
    play.filters.headers.allowActionSpecificHeaders=true

Then add header override:
    Ok("Index").withHeaders(SecurityHeadersFilter.CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY_HEADER -> "default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;")

~ https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SecurityHeaders#Action-specific-overrides

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Play but a universally effective way to *add* things to your CSP is using the meta tag in addition to the header. Framework/library support for dynamic is somewhat rare.

From http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/

> CSPs preferred delivery mechanism is an HTTP header. It can be useful,
>   however, to set a policy on a page directly in the markup. Do that
>   using a meta tag with an http-equiv attribute:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src
 https://cdn.example.net; child-src 'none'; object-src 'none'">
```

> This can’t be used for frame-ancestors, report-uri, or sandbox.

**Note**: the policy in the meta tag does not overwrite the header value, it's as if you had sent two headers: they are additive.